# "Proper" use of multiple inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, class

One day I read in the book (probably Head First Java, not sure). It says that "there's only **one** good usage of multiple inheritance used in a C++ library."

(There was a name of the library, but I forgot it) What library properly used multiple inheritance, and how multiple inheritance used?

Comment: So, does it say what is the "only one good usage of multiple inheritance"?

Comment: @VJo: "(There was a name of the library, but I forgot it)"

Comment: @VJo : yes, but I don't remember... :(

Comment: if iostream is the answer, throw the book away. Iostreams are very badly designed. There are good examples of well designed multiple inheritance, either *à la* Java or *à la* Eiffel in C++. Another good example is COM. Different languages have different traditions, and multiple inheritance is *not* in the tradition of Java. It is in the tradition of C++ though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that you can use multiple inheritance for is for [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin). You can use mixins to add functionality to a class that is defined in another class (the class that you're mixing in).

A link specifically about mixins in C++: [MixinsForCeePlusPlus](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MixinsForCeePlusPlus)

Answer (score 2):

`iostream` use multiple inheritance for streams that support both reading and writing. The class `iostream` inherits from both `istream` and `ostream` for that reason.